# How to add custom request header to testcafe test suite?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I have a bunch of tests that I am running through testcafe. Now I need to add a custom request header for each test that uniquely identifies the call is originating from the testcafe suite and not a real user.

Is there a way to add the custom header to all the test cases at once?

I was looking at [this](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/intercept-http-requests.html#mock-http-requests) but it seems like I would need to update each fixture to get this working. So, I wanted to know if there's a way I can set it on a top level file before calling the test suite?

EDIT:

So, this is what I am currently doing. I have created a new file that contains the class:

```
import { RequestHook } from 'testcafe';

class CustomHeader extends RequestHook {
    constructor () {
        // No URL filtering applied to this hook
        // so it will be used for all requests.
        super();
    }
    
    onRequest (e) {
        e.requestOptions.headers['my_custom_variable'] = 'my_value';
    }

    onResponse (e) {
        // This method must also be overridden,
        // but you can leave it blank.
    }
}

const customHeader = new CustomHeader();
export default customHeader;
```

And then in my each test file, update the fixtures to be like this:

```
import { customHeader } from 'customer_header'

fixture(`Test app avail`)
  .page(appURL)
  .requestHooks(customHeader)
  .beforeEach(async() => {
    await myTestfunction();
  });
```

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to specify hooks on the test run level. But, if updating each fixture is not reasonable in your case, you can use the workaround [posted](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4323#issuecomment-684641251) in the discussion about this feature. In order to apply your request hook to each fixture in the test suite you'll need to change "setup.js" (from the workaround above) as follows:

```js
export const fixture = (...args) => global.fixture(...args)
    .requestHooks(customHeader)
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        console.log('each');
    });
```